# Disable input text field which are coming on future month in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

i have static table columns for each month and static table body columns as input text for each month.i am having a problem in creating logic to disable future month input text.
thank in advance
[code of my html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhryD.png)

[i want to disable input of future month for example november and december](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbcji.png)

Comment: add readonly to input <input type="text" readonly>

Answer (score 0):

in angular you can use the property [disabled] on input field and call a component a method

for sample you can create a method and pass in parameter the monthNumber

```
<input [disabled]="isFutureMonth(0)"/> // for january
<input [disabled]="isFutureMonth(1)"/> /// for febrary
```

and in the component's controller we can propose you to :

1. stored somewhere the current month
2. create a method that check if input month is in the future or not

   export class MyComponent {

   ```
    currentMonth:number;

    constructor() {
      this.currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
    }

    isFutureMonth(monthNumber:number):boolean {
      return (monthNumber > this.currentMonth);
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: hello jeremy denis you are right my problem is soved actually both you and KEVAL helped i used both the concepts and now everthing is working. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional field in your static table for monthNumber.
For ex: Jan = 1, Feb = 2, Mar = 3.....

After that in you component declare two new variable `todaysDate` =  `todaysDate: Date = new Date();` and `currentMonth` = `currentMonth: any`

Then create method to get current month as below

```
getMonth() {
    this.month = this.todaysDate.getMonth() + 1;
}
```

Call this method from `ngOnInit()`, you will get current month.

After this in your HTML file add `[disabled]` in your input fields
`[disabled]="(i.month > currentMonth)"`